# iOS Memory issues

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management

I've been using the following code without almost any problems, but today Xcode begun to complain about it BIGTIME. I almost went nuts before I could find were the bug/memory leak indeed was. Xcode said "message sent to deallocated instance". I commented a couple of lines (the releases) and it stopped crashing.

The thing is, I'm completely lost here... shouldn't I release those to avoid memory leaks? I'm targeting iOS 4.0 for this project, so manual memory managment is a must.

```
+ (NSString*)reformatRule:(NSString*) ruleStr {
    NSString *bufRule = [[[NSString alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSString *buf = [[NSString alloc] init];
    char c = 0;
    NSString *value = [[NSString alloc] init];
    for(int i=0;i<[ruleStr length];i++){
        c = [ruleStr characterAtIndex:i];
        if([self isCharacterOrDigit:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",c]]){
            buf = [buf stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",c]];
        }else{
            DLog(@"says:%@",buf);
            value = [buf stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
            //[buf release];
            //buf = [[NSString alloc] init];
            buf = @"";
            if (![value isEqualToString:@""]) {
                if ([value isEqualToString:CONDITION_AND] || [value isEqualToString:CONDITION_OR]) {
                    bufRule = [bufRule stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",value]];
                }else{
                    bufRule = [bufRule stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@)",value]];
                }
            }

            if(c!=' '){
            bufRule = [bufRule stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",c]];
            }
        }
    }

    // [value release]; COMMENTED THIS LINE
    // [buf release]; AND THIS ONE TOO
    return bufRule;
}
```

Comment: Did you try running the analyzer?  Or any other tools?

Comment: Why don't you just use ARC? I can't imagine how many people wouldn't be here if they just used ARC.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII -- You don't think they'd just go on to the next problem?  ARC may very likely turn out to be an "enabler" of sloppy coding practices.

Comment: @HotLicks at least it would help to stop the flood of questions tagged `memory-management`.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII -- No problem -- we need a replacement for the `homework` tag anyway.

Comment: @HotLicks, if you think automatic memory management techniques are somehow a fad, I have bad news for you.  They're here to stay, and on the whole, they make programming significantly easier, and less error prone.  ARC is an enormous step forward for Objective-C, and newbies should be using it.  Even moderately seasoned developers mess up memory management regularly, and with ARC available to help, it's really unnecessary to spend so much time debugging these kinds of problems that could be better spent elsewhere.

Comment: Hey @RichardJ.RossIII, which part of "I'm targeting iOS 4.0 for this project, so manual memory managment is a must" didn't you understund? Of course I would be using ARC if I could, but the project I am working for, aims to the biggest audience posible so I must stick to version < iOS 4.0!!!

Comment: @IgnacioOroná ARC is supported for iOS 4.0+ The only difference is that it doesn't support weak references until iOS 5.0 https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: @Nate -- Yes, and there are many languages that do "automatic memory management" much better than Objective-C/ARC.  But the real point is that if someone is too lazy to learn the basics of pre-ARC memory management in Objective-C (when using that version), they really shouldn't be using Objective-C, but should stick with a simpler language.  Like BASIC.

Comment: @HotLicks, so because Objective-C is behind other languages with automatic memory management, we should just ignore what tools it **does** provide us with?  Do you walk 10 miles to work because your Toyota Camry isn't as fast as Formula One race cars?  And last time I checked, the iOS SDK doesn't support BASIC development.  Your comments are beyond absurd.

Comment: @Nate -- I see you chose to ignore my point, which is that the OP is not yet sufficiently skilled to reasonably use Objective-C.  He'll only learn bad habits.

Comment: @HotLicks,  I didn't ignore anything. Your point is pure nonsense.  *Reasonably* using Objective-C means learning its features, and ARC is one of those features.  Richard's comment was spot on.  **Especially** for newbies, they need to stop doing it the hard(er) way, and take advantage of something useful that was added to the language.

Comment: Newbies need to understand things like object allocation, "leaks", how to read documentation, how to use development tools, et al, before tackling Objective-C.  If they don't, they'll never really understand the language and will just be "maze bright".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line converts `buf` from a retained pointer to an autoretained one:

```
buf = [buf stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",c]];
```

Similarly the `value` line a couple of lines down.

If you're not going to use ARC, you really need to understand storage management a *lot* better.

Comment: Thanks @Hot-Licks great answer! My question now is, how could can you know "programatically" if a method returns an autoreleased pointer? or if it changes the reference count? or if it does not? (I'm specially interested in knowing how you knew it was returning an autoreleased/pointer)

Comment: This is Cocoa 101:  Naming conventions.  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH If you didn't call "alloc" "retain" or "copy" then you don't call "release"

Comment: @IgnacioOroná -- It's all in those chapters you skipped over while studying Objective-C.

Comment: @HotLicks or "mutableCopy" but I didn't intend for that list to be exhaustive